# Change scene after buy

Tags: unity-game-engine

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xy46K.png)  after I click buy to change to a new scene it appears this error. What can I do? This is unity error? or because of the script?

TypeLoadException: Could not resolve type with token 01000025 (from typeref, class/assembly SimpleJson.SimpleJson, UnityEngine, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null)
UnityEngine.Purchasing.PurchasingManager.OnPurchaseSucceeded (System.String id, System.String receipt, System.String transactionId) (at

```css
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class PurchaseScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public void BuyComplete(UnityEngine.Purchasing.Product product)
    {
        Application.LoadLevel("51");
    }
   
    public void BuyFailed(UnityEngine.Purchasing.Product product, UnityEngine.Purchasing.PurchaseFailureReason fa)
    {
        Debug.Log("PURCHASE FAILED");
    }
}
```

Comment: It'd be great if you would put the actual error in the question.

Comment: it is the blue " error "

Comment: I mean copy the error message and paste it into the question, not everyone is going to go to third party sites to view an image.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the "proper" way of loading scenes is a bit different your code looks to be using a deprecated function. Try to look at this: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.SceneManager.LoadScene.html

Comment: Nvm, didnt realize he was using the "Application" version to load a new scene.